# Rails locate installed .html.erb files after using gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Hi there I installed blogo gem https://github.com/greyblake/blogo
And it works perfectly well.
But I have problem trying to find where `blog.html.erb` files are located.(To change header, add links to my site and whatever)
I really can't find them. I've searched everywhere I guess. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[That file](https://github.com/greyblake/blogo/blob/master/app/views/layouts/blogo/blog.html.erb) is hidden inside the gem. It is located in `app/views/layouts/blogo/blog.html.erb` but as I said it's tucked away.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/greyblake/blogo), you are instructed to configure what you need inside of the `config/initializers/blogo.rb` file.

Answer (score -1):

What you really need to do is to **work out how to search for files, and text strings, within your codebase**.  I don't just mean this because that would have saved you posting this very simple question: it's for your own benefit.  Once you start coding you will find yourself needing to find stuff (files, variable names, methods etc) ALL THE TIME.  The quicker you learn how to quickly find them, the more time you'll save.

If you're using an IDE (development software) it will have built-in search facilities which are probably very powerful.  They might take a little bit of config, eg adding the folder where your gems live.